# Combine 2 batch files into 1 but keep them running in 2 command windows

Tags: batch-file

I have 2 batch files which I currently run seperatly however I would like to combine them in 1 file I can trigger.

Batch file 1

```
echo on
pushd C:\(location of front end code)
call npm install
call gulp build 
Pause
```

Batch file 2

```
echo on
pushd C:\(location of backend/database code)
call activator -jvm-debug 9999 -Dconfig.file='<application.conf file location>
pause
```

What I would like to do is have these in a single batch file which runs the code in batch file 1, then opens a 2nd command window while keeing the first open and runs the code in batch file 2?

Comment: `start` can open another window, but this implies another `cmd` instance... I don't think this is possible...

Comment: To have the code in one file have the batch start itself with a batch2 argument that you check at begin and do a goto  :batch2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your issue can be salved by creating another cmd instance via `start cmd /k`

The `start` command will allow you to create a new window and execute code. The syntax: `START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]`

For the `[options]` there are a few gates you can use:

- **/K** - *Will run the new window and keep it open after execution.*
- **/C** - *Will run the new window and close it after execution.*

Because of how the *start* syntax is, you will have to use the `&` to link multiple commands. Keep note that the single `&` separates commands on a line. The `&&` will execute the next command only if previous command's errorlevel is 0.

```
@ECHO OFF
@SETLOCAL
@TITLE Active Window01
@GOTO :WIN1

:WIN1
::Code for 1st batch
pushd C:\(location of front end code)
call npm install
call gulp build 

echo Code finished, opening 2nd task window.
goto :WIN2

:WIN2
::Open new task window after 1st task.
start "Active Window02" cmd /C "@ECHO OFF & pushd C:\(location of backend/database code) & call activator -jvm-debug 9999 -Dconfig.file='<application.conf file location> & Echo Code finished, now pausing. & pause."

::To pause 1st batch
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

if "%~1" == "/label2" goto :label2
goto :label1

:label2
pushd "C:\location of backend\database code"
call activator -jvm-debug 9999 -Dconfig.file="application.conf file location"
pause
exit /b 0

:label1
pushd "C:\location of front end code"
call npm install
call gulp build
start "%ComSpec%" /i cmd /c "%~f0" /label2
pause
exit /b 0
```

Running the script will `goto :label1` as the 1st argument
is not `/label2`.

It will eventually reach the `start` command and run the
same script with a argument of `/label2`. The first argument of
`start` is the window title which is set as the value from
`%ComSpec%`.

The 2nd script instance will `goto :label2` as the 1st argument
matches the `if` comparison.

Comment: this worked but went with the simpliar option below thanks